# What is the use for font files from font-awesome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I am using `font-awesome` and it works fine with its CDN extension for CSS files. Following is a simple example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <i class="fa fa-adjust"></i>
    </body>
</html>
```

The example runs fine, but from [the CDN](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome), I also get links for `.otf`, `.eot`, `.svg`, `.ttf`, `.woff` files. What is the use of these files if the example renders well with only `.css` file extension?

Comment: If the font is not supported by Browser/OS then that font will be used

Comment: That are you web fonts, those are included in main css file "check section FONT PATH"  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css

Comment: @SilentTremor - That means once we include the css, we dont need ever to add these other files after that? If so, why the links are provided separately?? Any specific reason?

Comment: The links are provided for you to use separately of that css file, if you want to use only the fonts. But since u are using font awesome it's more that enough to reference only the css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because if you see that css file you will find the links or code which is importing or calling all these files. basically css is just the code which shows and calls the particular icon. but that icon is in those otf and other files. its like you can only call img tag in the html but why you need a image in your website to be kept in a website.
hope it clears

thanks

Comment: Ok, but as a user, now I only need to call the cdn of the .css file. I would never need to extend the other files from cdn (.otf,.ttf,.eot,etc.)?

Comment: @Peterson No, it depends on the browser.

Comment: @BF - But when all other files are already included in the .css one (see above link), then why still we would ever have their external links again in our code (apart from inside the .css files which already includes these other type of font files)? https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css

Answer (score 6):

While some browsers support the TTF/OTF formats as webfonts, Internet Explorer generates an error unless the font is set to Installable Embedding mode. This behavior is reproduced when neither .woff nor .eot variants are served to IE.

This can be remedied by setting the fsType flag in the font file to 0000, representing Installable Embedding mode, using one of the following utilities:
Using the ttembed-js npm module

```
npm install -g ttembed-js
ttembed-js path/to/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
ttembed-js path/to/FontAwesome.otf
```

or, within node.js:

```
var callback = function(error, oldFsType) {
    if (error) {
        console.error('Something went wrong.', error);
        return;
    }
    if (oldFsType === '0000') {
        console.log('fsType is already 0000; no action taken.');
    } else {
        console.log('fsType successfully changed from ' + oldFsType + ' to 0000.');
    }
}
var ttembed = require('ttembed-js');
ttembed({filename: './path/to/fontawesome-webfont.ttf'}, callback);
ttembed({filename: './path/to/FontAwesome.otf'}, callback);
```

Using the original ttembed

```
git clone https://github.com/hisdeedsaredust/ttembed.git
cd ttembed
make
./ttembed path/to/fontawesome-webfont.ttf path/to/FontAwesome.otf
```